# ExtJS Cartesian Bar Chart Listeners

Tags: extjs, charts

I have requirement with the ExtJS Cartesian Bar Chart that to attach an event listener. The event listener listen for the click event in the bar in the chart. I tried to add listeners to the Cartesian chart itself as per the documentation. But it is not working. Please help with a solution

Comment: Post the code that you have tried....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this plugin to your chart.

```
plugins: {
    ptype: 'chartitemevents',
    moveEvents: true
},
```